# Help with tuning this UPDATE Query or possible re-write

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2014, performance-tuning

I have below SQL query which runs on avg. 40 secs and need some guidance where can i improve it or possibly re-write:

```
   Declare @status_D INT,
      Declare @StatusIP INT,
      Declare @Status_F INT,
    
    SELECT @status_D = Id From Batchtablestatus (NOLOCK) Where desc ='Value1';
    SELECT @StatusIP = Id From Batchtablestatus (NOLOCK) Where desc ='Value2';
    SELECT @Status_F = Id From Batchtablestatus (NOLOCK) Where desc ='Value3'

BEGIN TRAN

 UPdate U
        SET 
         U.[id]= @StatusIP,
         U.[EnabledDate]= Getdate()
         OUTPUT deleted.col1,
         deleted.col2,
         deleted.col3,
         deleted.col4,
         Inserted.id

FROM (

SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM BatchChangeTable WITH (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK)
WHERE [id] IN ( @status_D ,Status_F)
ORDER BY [ModifiedTime] )U;

  COMMIT TRAN
```

> I am getting warning from blitzcache as Forced serialization,
> Expensive sort, non-sargable and Merge join "Mant to Many" = True

The only index we had is on id which is a NC index with id as leading key column.

I will try to update my question if execution plan if i can. Table in SELECT is around 100 million as of now. Also it has PK/CI on col1.

I have asked users why we do * in that TOP which pulls almost 50+ columns but in update use just fewer, may b i am thinking wrong but just came to my mind.

Adding index to modified time also does not seem to help.

Please suggest what else can be checked. Thanks

plan-
Index seek has happened on NC index id
[image]

Comment: 1) Could u add the table definition? 2) could u paste the plant to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ? 3) you are ordering the whole table whixh is aperformance hog.  Is id the PK? I eould say a preselect of ordering only PK then selecting the columns could be better

Comment: I would try on getting 1, 2 is slightly not possible due to secure env. Id is non clustered index, col1 is the PK/CI on the BatchChangeTable

Comment: pastetheplan obfuscates the tables etc while providing statistics

Comment: @Newbie-DBA 1) You are correct to question the `SELECT ... *`, it is bad practice in most cases to do that. List only the columns you need in the `SELECT` list. This typically reduces the amount of data that needs to be loaded from disk, and also can sometimes result in a better **execution plan** based on if the fields you're selecting are covered by the index used. 2) Without seeing your **execution plan** it's like asking us to pour you a glass of water, without a glass or water, there's unfortunately not much that can be recommended. Please consider obfuscating it and posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Warnings

- The forced serialization is because of the `OUTPUT` (with no target or to a `@table` variable will cause this, but not a `#temp` table)
- The expensive
  sort is because you're ordering by `ModifiedTime` without a supporting index and query pattern
- The non-SARGable
  warning is because ([if I remember how I wrote the check correctly](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/pull/1450)),
  of the local variables.

### How to fix it

You'll need a good supporting index:

```
CREATE INDEX super_awesome
ON dbo.BatchChangeTable
    (id, ModifiedTime)
INCLUDE
    (EnabledDate);
```

But the way the query is written, `IN` will be interpreted as a range predicate, and the `ORDER BY ModifiedDate` will likely still cause a Sort operation. You'll need to change the form to [use two equality predicates](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/are-table-variable-indexes-ever-useful/) with a `UNION ALL` in order to take full advantage of the index.

You're also going to need to rewrite your query to use dynamic SQL so that you don't get hit with the [side effects of local variables](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/yet-another-post-about-local-variables/).

The finished product will look something like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

/*I'm guessing here, address local factors*/
CREATE TABLE #output(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, id int)

/*Use parameterized dynamic SQL*/
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N''

/*Hello I am your friend*/
SET @sql += N'
UPDATE u
SET
    u.id = @StatusIP,
    u.EnabledDate = GETDATE()
OUTPUT
    deleted.col1,
    deleted.col2,
    deleted.col3,
    deleted.col4,
    Inserted.id
INTO #output 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (5000)
        b.*
    FROM 
    (
         SELECT 
             b2.*
         FROM BatchChangeTable AS b2 WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK)
         WHERE b2.id = @status_D
         
         UNION ALL 
         
         SELECT 
             b2.*
         FROM BatchChangeTable AS b2 WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK)
         WHERE b2.id = @Status_F
         ORDER BY b2.ModifiedTime
    ) AS b
    ORDER BY b.ModifiedTime
) AS u;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@status_D int,
                     @StatusIP int,
                     @Status_F int',
                     @status_D,
                     @StatusIP,
                     @Status_F;

SELECT 
    o.*
FROM #output AS o

COMMIT TRAN;
```

You'll need to tailor this a little to suit your actual situation, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

ideas based on available info:

1. add nonclustered index (id, ModifiedTime) or (ModifiedTime, id), not sure based on your info
2. try to rewrite update
   .

code:

```
update BatchChangeTable 
        SET 
         U.[id]= @StatusIP,
         U.[EnabledDate]= Getdate()
         OUTPUT deleted.col1,
         deleted.col2,
         deleted.col3,
         deleted.col4,
         Inserted.id
where col1 in (select top 5000 col1 from BatchChangeTable WITH (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK)
WHERE [id] IN ( @status_D ,Status_F)
ORDER BY [ModifiedTime])
```